# Database Listener does not capture inserts made by SSIS

Tags: c#, sql, ssis, listener, sqldependency

I am using SqlTableDependency (https://tabledependency.codeplex.com/) as a database listener to capture inserts made in my database. It works well when I am manually inserting data and/or when running stored procs to insert data. However, when we used SSIS to dump data, the listener does not capture it anymore. Is it because the SSIS does a bulk insert?

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated much.

Thank you.

Comment: How about using database triggers for this kind of stuff and not take dependency on any external tools

Comment: I am using my database listener inside my console application to capture and return the id of the inserted data to generate a PDF. Would that be possible using triggers?